# Duda con llamada al sistema fork()

Tags: c, linux, unix

He leido sobre el funcionamiento de la llamada fork() y hasta ahora tengo entendido que esta hace una copia del proceso que se esta corriendo y por medio d euna bifurcación es posible saber si estamos en el proceso padre o hijo como en el siguiente ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora que segun yo entiendo como funciona esta función, estoy tratando de hacer un programa que cree dos procesos hijos de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según mi lógica la salida de este programa debería ser:
"I'm in the child 1"
"I'm in the child 2"
Sin embargo el programa no siempre imprime eso en pantalla. Algunas veces imprime unicamente
"I'm in the child 1"
Y quisiera saber por qué pasa esto ? Si segun yo, el proceso padre crear un proceso hijo y en la parte del if donde debería ir el código del padre creo otro proceso (child 2) y este debería imprimir su mensaje sin problemas.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme a entender por qué pasa esto, por favor ?

Comment: Tal vez no esta haciendo flush el stdout ¿Intentaste agregar fflush(stdout) antes del return? Algo que cabe aclarar tambien es que la salida no necesariamente va a ser en un orden predefinido

Comment: voy a intentar hacer fflush con el stdout. Si por supuesto, yo se que la salida no será en un orden fijo, sin embargo ambos procesos hijos deberian imprimir su mensaje en pantalla en el orden que sea. Muchas gracias ! lo voy a intentar y te diré si funcionó

Comment: Adelante, la verdad es que trate de replicar el error con el codigo que publicaste y no pude ):

Comment: Bueno, es que el error aparece una de cada 100 veces aprox. jajaja te comento que intenté lo de fflush y no funcionó :( pero sigo buscando ;)

Comment: Tu lógica es correcta. El programa debe imprimir los dos mensajes. Lo que puede ocurrir es que, antes de que imprima el segundo, el padre termine y reaparezca el _prompt_ del sistema operativo. El segundo mensaje podría aparecer tras el prompt o mezclado con él, pero debería estar de todas formas. Fíjate bien por si es eso.

Comment: @abulafia efectivamente, era eso. Muchas gracia

Answer (score 0):

me respondo a mi mismo con la respuesta, les comento, estoy usando code blocks como IDE y no me habia fijado en esto:
Resulta que el mensaje "I'm in the child 2" Si aparece, es solo que como comentaron antes, el orden  de la impresion en pantalla no siempre es el mismo, asi que cuando yo creia que no se imprimia el segundo mensaje, resulta que simplemente no lo estaba viendo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]